# How do I totally remove nd reinstall MySQL in my Ubuntu desktop PC

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I had installed MySQL in my Ubuntu OS PC. But during the config setup, I had mistakenly set Disallow root login to Y. The MySQL Workbench was not able to connect. I accessed the config file from the terminal prompt:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql.cnf
```

I noticed that it did not have any config. It only had the following lines:

```
#The MySQL client configuration file
#Refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/mysql-command-options.html
[mysql]
```

I entered the line
bind_address = 0.0.0.0
password = mypassword

But still unable to connect MySQL Workbench. From the terminal, I was now unable to login to MySQL

I tried to uninstall MySQL and reinstall it with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get remove dbconfig-mysql
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

The last command did not proceed with the configuration. I had hoped that I will be able to set the Disallow root login to Y.

How do I uninstall/ reinstall MySQL and have MySQL Workbench connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved my problem First I uninstalled MySQL (again). Next, I decided to install XAMMP. I followed the how-to steps in one online resource. I launched the XAMPP and was able to connect to localhost/phpmyadmin. I was able to create a database and table, and add a record